# Can't create a visualization in Kibana (no compatible fields) - but I have compatible fields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'd appreciate any help with this, I'm really stuck.

I am trying to create a simple visualization in Kibana, a line graph based on a number value in my data (origin_file_size_bytes).  When I try to add a Visualization graph, I get this error:

**No Compatible Fields: The "test*" index pattern does not contain any of the following field types: number or date**

My actual index does contain a field with number, as does my data.

Thank you for any help!

Andrew

Here's a sample entry from the Discover Menu:

{ 
  "_index": "lambda-index",
  "_type": "lambda-type",
  "_id": "LC08_L1TP_166077.TIF",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 2,
  "_source": {. 
    "metadata_processed": {
      "BOOL": true.
    },
    "origin_file_name": {
      "S": "LC08_L1TP_166077.TIF"
    },
    "origin_file_size_bytes": {
      "N": "61667800"
    }
  }
}

My Index pattern classifies as a string, even though it isn't:

**origin_file_size_bytes.N  string**

[image: Kibana Index Pattern]

[image: Kibana Discover error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot aggregate on a string field. As seen from the screenshot above, your field has been indexed as string and NOT as a number. Elasticsearch dynamically determines mapping type of data if it is not explicitly defined. Since, you ingested the field as a string ES determined, correctly, that the field is of type string. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_dynamic_mapping) link.

For ex. if you run the below to index a document with 2 fields as shown without an explicit mapping, ES creates message field as type 'string' and size field as type 'number' (long)

```
POST my_index\_doc\1
{
  "message": "100",
  "size": 100
}
```

Index your field into ES as a number instead and you should able to aggregate on it.

Comment: Thank you!   I started researching how to do this without deleting and recreating my index but haven’t found a clear answer yet. Maybe there’s a way to create an additional index. I will keep looking.  Thanks!

Comment: Starting to make a little progress!  I created a new index per these instructions, I created each mapping b hand (text and integers) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html. The index appears correct now, but I can't create a new index pattern (required for the visualization).  Still researching.

Comment: Let me know if you are stuck! Glad to help

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the right track!  The root cause was my input data.  My input data was sent as nested JSON, so the nested pieces were interpreted as strings even when they contained numbers.  I fixed this by creating a new index, and then changing what I sent to Elasticsearch.  Thanks again!